# js-cookie not setting cookies when secure flag is enabled

Tags: cookies, js-cookie

I have this simple function that sets a cookie

`Cookies.set('accesstoken', res.data.accesstoken);`

I wanted to make it secure but whenever I put

`Cookies.set('accesstoken', res.data.accesstoken, { secure: true });`

The cookie is not set

Comment: Can you please share your Cookies function. Also are you using secure environment https??

Comment: @Sehdev im not using https, i think thats the issue, and Cookies function is one in the js-cookie npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the js-cookie [documentation](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie):

> **secure**
>
> > Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a
> >     secure protocol (https).
> >
> > Default: No secure protocol requirement.

You need to use `https` in order to set the cookie using `{secure:ture}`